# Wrong redirection with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I made an **URL Shortener** and shortened links looks like this: 
*http://patison.eu/06uoM*. My PHP code checks if this **06uoM** is in my database - if yes it will redirect to the correct page, if not it will open `index.php` file from `index_html` directory. It's bad because when I write URL to image uploaded on server it will open `index.php` because URL is not in database...

*http://patison.eu/forum/images/off.gif* - see?

This is how `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

---

Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: But `off.gif` does not exist in the images directory, which is why the request is being forwarded to `index.php`. This one works because the file exists: http://patison.eu/forum/images/buddies.png

Comment: how many .htaccess do you have in all the directories??  just this one?

Comment: when getting to buddies.gif it sends again to the index.php... maybe u forgot to add .giff  but not png?¿¿?¿

Comment: Did you make any changes? Now the url goes to youtube. Did you solved?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to let 404 errors happen on URLs like

> http://patison.eu/forum/images/off.gif

but not on URLs like

> http://patison.eu/06uoM

If that is the case, you can change your `.htaccess` code to this to limit the type of URLs rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Limit rewrites to urls like '/06uoM' or '/06uoM/', but not like '/forum/images/off.gif'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[0-9a-z]{5}/?$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```